# How to split collection into elements with flatMap

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have this type of input:
`List( (key1, List(1,2,3)), (key2, List(4,5)) )`
and I want to remap it the following way:
`List( (key1, 1), (key1, 2), (key1, 3), (key2, 4), (key2, 5) )`

I cannot figure out how to split a list into elements and still keep the key.

Comment: It turns out I made a mistake when I created the test input List and it was of a different type than presented here which led me down the wrong path. Thanks for the solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you tried but here is the simplest way I would do it:

```
val splitMe = List( (key1, List(1,2,3)), (key2, List(4,5)) )
splitMe.flatMap(v=> v._2.map(g => (v._1, g)))
```

Answer (score 11):

```
val flattened = list.flatMap({ case (k, l) => l.map((k,_)) })
```